# Identify Which column cause String or binary data would be truncated. : SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have application which will insert to multiple table with single click. these table has nearly 100 - 150 columns.

It's working fine but sometime anyone of the column makes the error String or binary data would be truncated. I know the error cause but i want to know which column in the cause for this issue.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Is it possible to identify in SQL server? Since my application is production side. I am not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: How are the inserts done: insert statements built in the app, insert statements inside Stored Procs on the DB side ?

Comment: Provide your insert query.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas I am doing my insert from SQL server Sp's. It is norml insert

Answer (score 4):

Import the data into a new table using `VARCHAR(MAX)` as the datatype for the columns. Then you can use `DATALENGTH` to get the maximum size of each column.

```
 SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(col1)) AS col1, MAX(DATALENGTH(col2)) AS col2, etc.
 FROM newTable
```

This will tell you which column(s) exceed the size of your column(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [MSDN blog](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name):

```
declare @table_name varchar(200)

set @table_name = 'Branch'

declare @max_length_default int, @column varchar(50), @max_length int, @max_length_string varchar(10)

create table #temp_table (column_name varchar(50), max_length int, max_length_default int)

declare @column_id int, @max_column_id int

select @column_id = min(b.column_id), @max_column_id = max(b.column_id) from sys.tables a, sys.columns b where a.[name] = @table_name and a.object_id = b.object_id --and b.system_type_id in ( 231, 167 )

-- select @column_id, @max_column_id

declare @command varchar(2000)

while(@column_id <= @max_column_id)
begin
    set @column = null

    select @column = b.name, @max_length_default = b.max_length from sys.tables a, sys.columns b where a.[name] = @table_name and a.object_id = b.object_id --and b.system_type_id in ( 231, 167 ) 
    and b.column_id = @column_id

    --select @column, @max_length_default

    if( @column is not null )
    begin

        set @command = 'insert into #temp_table(column_name, max_length, max_length_default) select ''' + @column + ''', max(len(cast([' + @column + ']as varchar(8000)))),' + cast(@max_length_default as varchar(5)) + ' from ' + @table_name + ' where [' + @column + '] is not null'

         --select @command

         exec(@command)        
    end

    set @column_id = @column_id + 1
end

select * from #temp_table

drop table #temp_table
```

Comment: Can you please explain this answer? what is difference in max_length and max_length_default ?

Comment: @VigneshKumar:- `max_length` is the maximum length of the value which is stored in the column and `max_length_default` is the value which you have provided while creating the column ie., the datatype length.

Comment: @VigneshKumar:- For example you create a table with column A as varchar(100) and then insert the value in this column as 'ABCDEF' then `max_length` is 6 and `max_length_default` is 100